# How do i a coordinate transformation for all vertices of an object

Tags: three.js

I want to translate all the vertex coordinates of an object to have them relative to the camera instead of the world coordinate origin. To do this, I just have to do this for each vertex

vertex position - camera position

That’s the easy math part.

The question:
How do I perform this operation on all vertices of an object?

//**************************************************************************************

Update:

I added the object to the camera but that doesn't prevent the GPU from calculating with the world coordinates of the object

```
import * as THREE from "../resources/libs/three/build/three.module.js";
import {GLTFLoader} from '../resources/libs/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'; 
import { ColladaLoader } from '../resources/libs/three/examples/jsm/loaders/ColladaLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from '../resources/libs/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';


class Main {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
        this.animate(); 
    }
            
    init(){
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            logarithmicDepthBuffer: true,
            antialias: true
        });
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        
        this.container = document.getElementById('container');
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

        
        const aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight; 
        const fov = 50;
        const near = 1e-6;
        const far = 1E27;
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x557799 );
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 10000000);
    
        this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
        this.controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
        this.controls.target.set( 0, 0, 9999980 );
        this.controls.update();
    
        this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    
        const loader = new ColladaLoader();
        loader.load( '../resources/models/stormtrooper/stormtrooper.dae', ( collada ) => {
            this.avatar = collada.scene;
            const animations = this.avatar.animations;

            this.avatar.rotation.z = Math.PI;           
            
            //Here i add the object to the camera
            this.camera.add(this.avatar);
            this.avatar.position.set( 0, 0, -20 );

            this.avatar.traverse( ( node ) => {
                if ( node.isSkinnedMesh ) {
                    node.frustumCulled = false;
                }
            });
            
            this.scene.add( this.camera );
        });
    
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.2 );
        this.scene.add( ambientLight );

        const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
        this.scene.add( this.camera );
        this.camera.add( pointLight );

    }//end init
    
    
    animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );  
        this.render();
    }//end animate
    
    
    render(){
        this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera); 
        
        const delta = this.clock.getDelta();
//      if ( this.mixer !== undefined ) {
//          this.mixer.update( delta );
//      }
    }//end render
}//end class


export {Main};
```

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Some discussion first...

There are much better ways to achieve the same effect. Not only would looping through the vertices be an expensive operation, but WebGL and the GPU are made to perform similar operations that can achieve the same effect natively, and not in the (comparatively) slow JavaScript environment.

### Let the local coordinate systems and GPU do their jobs

You best option is to simply add your mesh to the camera! Sounds silly, right? But `Camera` inherits from `Object3D`, which means it has its own local space. Using `myCamera.add( myMeshObject )` places `myMeshObject` into the camera's local space, which is exactly what you're looking for. Just remember that the camera looks down its own `-Z` axis, "up" is its `+Y` axis, and don't put your mesh closer to the camera than its `near` plane distance, and you should be good to go.

### If you really want to dig in there...

The vertices are all held in `mesh.geometry.attributes.position`. You can work with individual vertices using [`Vector3.fromBufferAttribute`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Vector3#api/en/math/Vector3.fromBufferAttribute) and [`BufferAttribute.setXYZ`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=bufferattribute#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.setXYZ) like this:

```js
const vertex = new Vector3()

for(let i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.attributes.position.count; ++i){
  vertex.fromBufferAttribute( mesh.geometry.attributes.position, i )
  // do something with vertex
  mesh.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( i, ...( vertex.toArray() ) )
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion sounds much more elegant and is easy. Then I would only have to multiply objects with the inverse matrix for camera rotations.

So that means the GPU never gets to see the large world coordinates of an object if this is a child of the camera, but only those from the local coordinate system of the camera?
I would like that.
Is the position of the camera important for the GPU as long as it is not used to calculate relationships to other objects?
I mean the active camera represents the screen and is always in the middle.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected. I pasted the code above. There you can see how I assign the object to the camera and set it to position z = -20. If the GPU would only calculate with distances relative to the camera, then that would be clean. However, the GPU still sees the world coordinates of the object.